# OSRM how to use my own map

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, osm2pgrouting, open-source-routing-machine

I download a cartography **bike** from the open data [data link](http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/pistes-cyclables/resource/234c8ee4-d9d8-4bb1-b957-3e5cd495a5aa) to Postgres then I convert it to **osm** using:

```
 python ogr2osm.py "PG:dbname=x user=x host=localhost" --sql="SELECT * FROM bike_network" --output=/home/vdm/bike_network.osm
```

But when I tried to extract the osm file using **osrm-extract** I had an error:

[image]

My question is it's possible to use **osrm** with other maps or it just works with openStreetMap maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the used speed profile (defined in a .lua file) depending on the specific attributes of your edges/ways.

By default, car.lua considers edges with common OSM attributes like `highway=secondary` which are suitable for cars.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, I have to create a bike profile (bicycle.lua)? but the problem I can not find this file (I'm using OSRM Docker).
It will be appreciated if you give me more hint or an example. Thank you for your reply. (I am new user in OSRM)

Comment: Sounds like your current profile (car.lua) can't find any routable ways (edges) in your input file (bike_network.osm). So take a look at both do determine which input car.lua expects and which input you are actually providing.

Comment: Yep, you have to create a "bike profile" (but the file name does not have to be bicycle.lua). In this profile you define which ways are suitable for bicycle routing and which speed is assumed for different road categories. For a introduction to OSRM profiles, see [this page](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/profiles.md). 
When executing `osrm-extract`, you specify your individual bike profile instead of the default car profile (which is in car.lua).